# create custom row animation to reload tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, caanimation

I know you can reload rows using reloadRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation.
how can you create an animation that is triggered when the row is replaced instead of the built in options.

an example would really help.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when "row is replaced "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean ...

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, 
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, 
insertSections:withRowAnimation: and 
deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
```

And also, the `"withRowAnimation`" is not a value, but an animation style: You can `override` it.

Comment: Yea, that worked. Though i was thinking of something that was created with core animation. But its fine, I managed to work with the built in options.